# Change the page in a WP7 application?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do I change the page in a WP7 application?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [NavigationService.Navigate.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591053(v=VS.92).aspx)

Example:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Schedules.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: Thank you again! :D Now how do I use an URI for this? Edit: Oh, thank you! :D

Comment: @driis - (deleted comment).

Answer (score 2):

There's additional information about page navigation on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626521.aspx).